# How exactly works this payloadFactory chained with an header mediator in a WSO2 ESB project?

Tags: soap, wso2, integration, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2** and I am working on a **WSO2 Enterprise Integrator** project containing this **ESB** project section (I think that my question is only related to ESB).

So my doubt is: I have an XML file defining an API. The flow starts with a **payloadFactory** mediator, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/xxxTest2" name="xxxTest2" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <!--  Create empty message to get all samples from DSS -->
            <!-- Get Sample ID -->
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <body/>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.int_val')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>

            <!-- 
             Adding an header that defines the actionr related to the "FindNotProcessed" DSS service
             used to retrieve all the unprocessed resource on the DB
            -->
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:FindNotProcessed"/>

            <!-- Log the request generated by the previous payloadFactory mediator: -->
            <log level="full"/>
            ...............................................................
            ...............................................................
            ...............................................................
</api>
```

My doubt is: this **payloadFactory** mediator generate and **empty message** because its content is:

```
<format>
    <body/>
</format>
```

The next element in the chain is the **header mediator**:

```
<header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:FindNotProcessed"/>
```

used to set a new header having **name="Action"** that specify (as value) the name of a **DSS** service to obtain some data from the DB.

Finnally the next element in the chain is a log mediator. It seems to me that is is used to log the message generated by the concatenation of the previous **payloadFactory** mediator chianed with the following **header** mediator.

```
This log mediator generate this log:

TID: [-1234] [] [2017-03-28 10:05:30,943]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  

To: /glisTest2, WSAction: urn:FindNotProcessed, SOAPAction: urn:FindNotProcessed, MessageID: urn:uuid:95913219-2ad1-4488-a260-78693f3bbde2, Direction: request, 

Envelope: 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <body xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

My doubts are:

1) Why is it generating an XML message that embedd a **soapenv** structure?

2) It depends by the fact that the **header** meadiator defines **scope="default"** that should coincide to **Synapse**. Because reading the official documentation: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Header+Mediator

it says:

> Scope: Select Synapse if you want to manipulate SOAP headers. Select
>   Transport if you want to manipulate HTTP headers.

so I think that settings in this way is generating a SOAP message and so is the reason because my message is into the **soapenv** structure.

Is it or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default, all the messages in the WSO2 EI/ESB will be treated as SOAP messages, that's why your payload  is enclosed in the soap envelope.
2. Headers actually work when you send the message to an endpoint, so if you have an endpoint http://hostname:port/abc/xyz , the Action (Soap Action) of the message will be set as urn:FindNotProcessed. It means that the message will go to the urn:FindNotProcessed operation of the endpoint, provided the endpoint is a soap endpoint.

Thanks